# How to query 2 different schema tables with different column name same information in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I query I do not get match list side by side and database reference fails, why?

I tried using one connection and two different schemas, first schema name table has same reference details with second table column, and I would like to compare side by side what equals exactly from rw.reference table 1, with table 2 qt.ref_number because they should match between both. I only get output data from top first query with rd.reference and second table does not list anything with, qt.ref_number, why postgresql does not cross database reference?

Query:

```
Select distinct
rd.reference, 
region1_scorecard

From local_dev.user.rawdata rd
Inner join customerid as id
on rd.site=id.site

union all

Select distinct
qt.ref_number, 
region2_decision

From local_dev.account.quote qt
Inner join rep_id id
on qt.application=id.application
Order by rd.reference
```

Comment: If the second query doesn't return any results within the UNION ALL, it is because it just doesn't return any results at all.  Fix the query to do the right thing before stuffing it into the UNION ALL.

Comment: @jjanes - would you have an example for me to review with specific fix? I'm curious to know why it's incomplete and why the book materials were not published using my type of query question.

Comment: 1) You can drop this `local_dev.` as Postgres does not do cross database references. 2) I am not seeing where `rw` is coming from? Or is this supposed to be `rd`? **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: @adrian klaver, update to question. query was fixed, removed rw. [Ran query and postgresql say, catalog must be specified when session catalog is not set]

Comment: To question add 1) Postgres version 2) Where Postgres was installed from? 3) The complete unedited error message.

Comment: @adrian klaver, disregard my questions and forget it.